# Qualtrics: Pressing enter key to emulate continue button

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I'm very new to JavaScript, and I'm currently trying to add a custom code to my Qualtrics survey that makes it so pressing the enter key continues the survey. I have a code that should be working; however, I'm getting an "Unexpected token )" error.

Here is the code:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {

            function(){
                that.clickNextButton();
            }

  }
    }

});
```

the "clickNextButton" function was found in the Qualtrics API document and is supposed to emulate the next button click. The function is clickNextButton(), but the example provided has the code as that.clickNextButton().

The example they use is below:

```
//Hides the next button and displays the question
//for 5 seconds before moving to the next page
this.hideNextButton();
var that = this;
(function(){that.clickNextButton();}).delay(5);
```

I don't need the hiding button function or the delay, but just wanted to include an example of how it is used.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: In their code, you see `var that = this`, which you didn't include in your code. See if this works :)

Comment: @VirginieLGB Thanks for the quick reply! I added it but I'm still getting the "unexpected token )" error.

Comment: You just forgot a ')' after the second-to-last bracket

Comment: @VirginieLGB Hmm oddly I'm still getting the same error. A ")" right after the bracket before "});" ? So, the 2nd to last line?

Comment: remove that.clickNextButton() from the function it is inside of, otherwise it will never be called, either that or you need to self invoke it by putting the entire function inside of perentheses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simplified version that works (updated to hide NextButton):

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()  {
    $('NextButton').hide();         
    document.on("keydown", function(e) {
         if (e.keyCode === 13) $('NextButton').click();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! As a follow up, if I wanted to hide the next button completely, (as of now it still appears), would I just add a line in that code with the hideNextButton()?

Comment: I've updated the answer above to hide the next button.  Please accept the answer.

Comment: Done. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the scope, or specifically where the function clickNextButton resides.
If you don't bother with the timeout you should be able to just remove the word 'that' from your Qualtrics.SurveyEngine function and it should work fine.

It's possible the function is not available in your current scope.  So if removing 'that' doesn't work.  Put it back in and put var that = this; in the line before your function call.  It's far from  a tidy way to do things at all but it may fix things for you.

Worth reading this.
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Didn't Meatloaf say something like... I'd do anything for scope.... but I don't do THAT?

Comment: It should be in the scope, I will check that out, Thanks! However, it seems like I'm getting a syntax error.

Comment: Hi not sure if you are still stuck with this.  But if where you call clickNextButton(), in the line before type in 
    debugger;
Then open up the developer tools (ctrl-shift-i) and run the code it should stop just before the function call.  Now you can type things in to see what you get.  In the console, try typing in 
   this;
Explore from there.  See if you can see the function in the scope.

Answer (score 0):

As said in my comment...See if it solves your error

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
    {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {

                function(){
                    that.clickNextButton();
                }

            }
        } ); // here was a missing bracket here
    });
```

Comment: Strangely, I'm still getting the same error. "Unexpected token )".

Answer (score 0):

So I have a video embedded in a question and I needed to disable to Next button for 15 seconds in that way I would know that autoplay video was watched.

And this worked for me so well:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
//Hides the next button and displays the question
//for 15 seconds before moving to the next page
this.disableNextButton();
var that = this;
(function(){that.enableNextButton();}).delay(15);

});
```

You can change the (15) seconds to any number, the Next Button will be activated and ready to be clicked next, but not automatically send you to next page.